# Is it possible to avoid OOM when loading a large data set using Cordova?

Tags: cordova, memory, firebase

I'm working on a Phonegap app that mostly deals with small JSON data sets coming from Firebase and being stored in local storage as well as into a javascript variable.

Occasionally though I need to handle larger JSON data sets (> 2Mb). When that happens, my device's memory usage grows hugely while pulling the data from Firebase and eventually crashes the application.

I ran it in Chrome on my computer and watched the memory usage go up to ~2.5Gb *while retrieving the data*. Once all the data was retrieved, the memory usage dropped way down to normal levels.

Has anybody else encountered this problem or know of a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to chunk your data

Firebase says

> For more information about chunking data and creating backups of big data, see the REST API's query parameters. Used together, startAt, limitToFirst, and shallow=true arguments can be used to index keys for any amount of data, and retrieve it in manageable segments.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-queries

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: This doesn't really help, because I still need to attach change listeners to the Firebase node. It's fine to chunk the data for the initial download, but once the data is downloaded, I need to do the following:
`ref.on("child_added", function(snap, prev) { // do stuff });` 

Unfortunately doing that causes my iOS Cordova app to crash with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in bmalloc:VMHeap::grow() . This seems to be a problem inherent to the WebView not being allowed to use more memory than the iOS will allow?