# Firebase: Listen for changes on child nodes after retrieving them all using .once()?

Tags: cordova, memory, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In reference to the answer given at [Is it possible to avoid OOM when loading a large data set using Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355819/is-it-possible-to-avoid-oom-when-loading-a-large-data-set-using-cordova) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28589093/3005222, I adapted the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/AgBN7/ provided by Kato to recursively page through a large Firebase data set (instead of relying on a user clicking the next page button).

It goes through a page of 100 nodes, using `ref.startAt(pri, lastKey).limitToFirst(100).once("value", ...)` and saves the data to a local variable. Then goes on to the next page and so on. At the end, I have a big local copy of the data that I use in my application. That's great but I'd now like to listen for changes and I have two options:

**Option 1:**
Change the paging code to use `.on()` instead of `.once()`

**Option 2:**
After getting all the data, have a `ref.on("value", ...)`

My question is, which option is better from a performance perspective? I did this whole paging thing because my Cordova app was crashing when retrieving all the data in one go with `ref.on("value",...)` and changing it to the paged method has fixed that. Now I wonder if I go with option 1, will it create lots of active listeners? If I go with option 2, will it make the paging redundant, i.e. what does adding a `.on()` listener do if I've already gone through all the data using `.once()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen for [child_changed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#child-events) on the parent of your nodes.

`ref.on('child_changed', callback)`

Every time a child is edited this will give you the updated value for that child.

**EDIT**

- `value` gives you the value of the node it is attached to
- `child_added` and `child_changed` gives you the value of the child of the node it is attached to

For example, if you attach the listeners to those events to a node containing a list of users:

- `value` will give you all the users every time a user is added/edited
- `child_added` and `child_changed` will give you just the user that has been edited/added

If you just want to keep the data synced in the client you can use both `child_added` and `child_changed` with the same callback that creates/updates the value in your local database copy.

Comment: Thanks Devid. I am already aware of child_changed, but I need child_added as well. So I was thinking of rather using .on('value', callback) because it covers both cases.

Comment: Also, as far as I'm aware, child_changed and child_added still retrieve all the data under the parent node, the same as .on('value')

Comment: Yes it does, I think indirectly you answered the question by explaining that `value` gives all data under the node for every edit. That will be very bad for a large node where child nodes are frequently getting edited! So I will rather use `child_added` and `child_changed`. Thanks :)